# Multiply values of each "path" in a given matrix for all columns

Tags: r, iteration, matrix-multiplication

Given an example of a matrix below:

| index | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.4 | 0.7 |
| 2 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.2 |

I would like to multiply all possible combination, selecting a value from each column multiply it over the row
eg:

```
0.1* 0.1* 0.1* 0.2* 0.2* 0.2* 0.7* 0.7* 0.4* 0.7

0.1* 0.6* 0.1* 0.2* 0.2* 0.2* 0.7* 0.7* 0.4* 0.7

0.1* 0.3* 0.1* 0.2* 0.2* 0.2* 0.7* 0.7* 0.4* 0.7

0.1* 0.1* 0.6* 0.2* 0.2* 0.2* 0.7* 0.7* 0.4* 0.7

0.1* 0.1* 0.3* 0.2* 0.2* 0.2* 0.7* 0.7* 0.4* 0.7

0.1* 0.1* 0.1* 0.1* 0.2* 0.2* 0.7* 0.7* 0.4* 0.7

0.1* 0.1* 0.1* 0.7* 0.2* 0.2* 0.7* 0.7* 0.4* 0.7
```

And so on...
Aim is to find the maximum value and get the row index selected for each 10 columns

I thought of creating all possible combinations into a row and the perform row multiplication for each row(which would be a combination) then use maximum.

How do I create a matrix with all possible "path" into a row, but then it would be difficult to identify which "path" the max value be for.

Comment: The logic is not clear to me. It looks like the fourth and first example are identical. What do you mean by "all possible combination"? How a combination is formed? Are you just changing the second term in the multiplication? With which logic?

Comment: Sorry I have added more examples. I am not just changing second term. Logic is to change each element of each column and multiplying 10 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make every permutations, where I let your data as `dummy`, use `expand.grid`

```
grid <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:3), 10))
```

Because `grid` is very huge, I'll use first five of `grid`

```
grid <- grid[c(1:5),]
```

Let's define a function to pull out grid rownumberd(?) values of `dummy`.

```
func <- function(df, idx) {
  vec <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(idx)){
    vec[i] <- df[as.numeric(idx[i]),i]
  }
  vec
}
```

Finally, get multiplications of those values like

```
apply(grid, 1, function(x) prod(func(dummy, x)))

          1           2           3           4           5 
1.09760e-06 6.58560e-06 3.29280e-06 6.58560e-06 3.95136e-05
```

If you want what maximize that is

```
grid[which.max(apply(grid, 1, function(x) prod(func(dummy, x)))),]
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10
5    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

## This is Second way

**HOWEVER** I think this way is much more efficient to get maximum value and it's index. Because all elements are positive,

```
x <- apply(dummy, 2, function(x) which.max(x))
 X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10 
  2   2   2   3   3   3   1   1   2   1 

prod(func(dummy,x))

[1] 0.01270609
```

## Large size example for second way

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(test ={x <- runif(250000,0,1)
                               y <- matrix(x, nrow = 5)
                               xx <- apply(y, 2, function(x) which.max(x))
                               
                               prod(func(y,xx))}
)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 test 86.0542 91.41575 111.9721 96.9571 140.7912 171.8394   100
```

Comment: Thanks!, what would the time complexity be as I have 50000 columns and 4-5 rows

Comment: @RahilVora I think the way you said may freeze your `R` sesison. Try second one.

Comment: second one? Like converting to rows by ```expand.grid``` and the perform row multiplication, but how would I get which "path"

Comment: @RahilVora Do not use grid. I write large above **This is Second way**. In that case, I'm not sure what is `path`, but if it's rowindexes, it's result of `apply(dummy, 2, function(x) which.max(x))` and `prod(func(y,xx))` is result of multiplication